# beautifulsoup4 failing to install with redis error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, redis

On Ubuntu 18/python 3.5.   My installs of beautifulsoup 4 fail with mention of redis server in the error message.  I do have redis installed on this machine.  Not sure why the bs4 install is getting fouled up with it (see install errors below).   I've tried ignoring the issue and then running a sample bs4 test which then fails.  Not sure if the failed parsing is related to the erroneous install or not.

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
html_doc = """
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html5lib")
print(soup.prettify)
```

Both html.parser and html5lib generate an error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/raiddisk/dev/pythonInterviews/src/HTML_beautsoup.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 314, in <module>
    from . import _html5lib
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/builder/_html5lib.py", line 70, in <module>
    class TreeBuilderForHtml5lib(html5lib.treebuilders._base.TreeBuilder):
AttributeError: module 'html5lib.treebuilders' has no attribute '_base'
```

Installation of bs4 error:

```
(venv) marshall@samson:/srv/raiddisk/dev/pythonInterviews$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-bs4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-154 linux-headers-4.4.0-154-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-164 linux-headers-4.4.0-164-generic
  linux-modules-4.4.0-164-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 64.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://mirrors.cs.umass.edu/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python3-bs4 all 4.4.1-1 [64.1 kB]
Fetched 64.1 kB in 0s (116 kB/s)     
(Reading database ... 371175 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-bs4_4.4.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-bs4 (4.4.1-1) over (4.4.1-1) ...
Setting up redis-server (2:3.0.6-1ubuntu0.4) ...
Job for redis-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status redis-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript redis-server, action "start" failed.
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-11-09 07:33:59 EST; 6ms ago
     Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
           man:redis-server(1)
  Process: 77504 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 77497 ExecStartPre=/bin/run-parts --verbose /etc/redis/redis-server.pre-up.d (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 09 07:33:59 samson systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced key-value store.
Nov 09 07:33:59 samson systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Unit entered faile...e.
Nov 09 07:33:59 samson systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Failed with result...'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package redis-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python3-bs4 (4.4.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 redis-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: did you try installing bs4 using [whl](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/#files)?

Comment: used pip install on the wheel file and it installed with no errors.  Thanks